# EaselJS: Access the stage from a MouseEvent

Tags: easeljs

If I have a MouseEvent firing, for example a pressmove, how do I access the stage, in order to issue this comment inside the event handler?

```
p.handlePressMove = function (event) {
    stage.setChildIndex(this, stage.getNumChildren()-1); //this is not working.
    stage.update();  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you function is scoped right, you can access the stage using a stored reference in the same scope. It is really important to scope listeners properly, for example using the `on()` method, which accepts a scope param:

```
btn.on("click", this.handleEvent, this);
```

If that isn't possible, you can always use the target of the MouseEvent (the thing that generated the event). All EaselJS objects that are on stage can get a reference to the stage:

```
p.handlePressMove = function (event) {
    var target = event.target; // Pressed object
    var stage = target.stage;
    // EaselJS 0.5x and earlier can use the method getStage() instead
}
```

Hope that helps.